# Extract id from URL using Angular (2+ till latest)

Tags: angular

Hi I am trying to extract the id part of the URL using Angular2.

```
http://localhost:3000/item/187809
```

I have been playing around with `ActiveRoute` within `onInit` but without luck

```js
     this.route.queryParams.forEach((params: any) => {
       console.log("QUERYPARAMS");
       console.log(params);
     });
```

Also tried subscribing to route change like this

```js
    this.routeSub = this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
       console.log(params);
       console.log(+params['id']);
    });
```

but `params` is just an empty object.

I am defining the route as a lazy route like this

```js
    {
        path: item',
        children: [
           { path: ':id', loadChildren: './item/item.module#ItemModule'},
        ]
    },
```

I think the problem is that I have a header component and a main component which holds the lazy loaded routed child. I am trying to load the id inside the header component.

Any idea what's missing?

Answer (score 145):

Subscribing and Unsubscribing to Route Parameters

1. Make sure you have configured a route that expects a parameter like so:

```js
{path: 'item/:id', component: SomeItemComponent}
```

2. Declare a variable for your route subscription. Import ActivatedRoute (not ActiveRoute) and inject it in your component constructor.

```js
private routeSub: Subscription;
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
```

3. Inside ngOnInit in the same component, you can access the data in the `params` observable by subscribing to it like so:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.routeSub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    console.log(params) //log the entire params object
    console.log(params['id']) //log the value of id
  });
}
```

4. Inside ngOnDestroy, unsubscribe to prevent memory leaks.

```js
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.routeSub.unsubscribe();
}
```

### Update - January 2021

There is a big difference between `route.params` and `route.queryParams`.

`route.params`, when subscribed to, returns an object with keys (that come from your **route parameters**, see step 1) and string values that are provided when navigating to the route. For example:

example.com/item/1

```js
{
  itemId: '1'
}
```

`route.queryParams`, when subscribed to, returns an object with keys and string values **that come from the [query string (wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) in the URL.** For example:

example.com/welcome?var1=abc&var2=cde

```js
{
  var1: 'abc',
  var2: 'cde'
}
```

`route.queryParams` will be `undefined` if a query string is not present in the URL. I believe OP, and some users in the comments have mistakenly used this instead of `route.params`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have it exactly like this except the route is lazy loaded see the updated question. But without luck, if I print out params property in chrome it gives me a strange Object __proto__ : Object

Comment: @doorman, sorry for the late reply, but that's because params is infact an object. See step 3 for how you can access a specific route parameter within that params object ('id' is the example).

Comment: this is not working.  OP says its a child route. This is probably why we are all getting undefined or null.  Any real solutions though?

Comment: @doorman sorry to bug you after a few years, but can you check to see if edits to this answer can close your question?

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. Seeing the different params through the log made it much easier to find the parameters I needed.

Answer (score 67):

I know I'm a bit late with a reply, but just in case you were still having problem please take a look at the Angular documentation.

[angular routing tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5#extract-the-id-route-parameter)

Look at the example from the link.

Start by importing ActivatedRoute:

```js
    import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
```

Then inject it in the constructor

```js
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
```

And in OnInit()

```js
    ngOnInit(): void {
        const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    }
```

and like this you don't need to worry about any Observables directly.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: **DON'T USE THIS** => If the user types another `id` in browser's address-bar, absolutely nothing happens! (subscribe like other answers describe, and refresh anything depending on `id`)

Answer (score 12):

I suspect the issue is that you're using `queryParams` instead of just `params`.

params: An Observable that contains the required and optional parameters **specific to the route.**

queryParams: An Observable that contains the query parameters **available to all routes.**

so try this:

```js
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       console.log(params);
       console.log(+params['id']);
    });
```

Answer (score 12):

You have **multi options** to get `id`

```js
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
```

**1-With the help of** `params`

```js
    const id= this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
```

or

```js
    const id = this.route.snapshot.params.id // any param name after "params"
```

**2-With the help of** `paramMap`

```js
    const id= this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')
```

**3-**`subscribe` to `params` (do not forget to unsubscribe)

```js
      private subscription: Subscription

      constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.subscription = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
          const id = params['id']
        })
      }

     //To prevent memory leak
      ngOnDestroy(): void {
        if (this.subscription)
          this.subscription.unsubscribe()
      }
```

### UPDATED

Imagine, you have the following route:

```js
    {
      path: "",
      component: LayoutComponent,
      children: [
        {
          path: "action/:id", component: ChildComponent
        }
      ]
    }
```

If you are in the LayoutComponent and you want to get params of ChildComponent you have to use the following way:

```js
    this.route.children.forEach(child => {
      child.params.subscribe(params => {
          const id = params['id']
      })
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I have faced the same problem while working with Angular 8, and solved it by:

1. At first, import ActivatedRoute:

```js
    import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
```

2. Then, Inject ActivatedRoute in the constructor:

```js
    constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}
```

3. Your ngOnit method will look like this.

```js
    ngOnInit(){
        const id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    }
```

I found it from the [official documentation of Angular](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5#extract-the-id-route-parameter).

Answer (score 3):

```js
    this.routeSub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       console.log(params);
       console.log(+params['id']);
    });
```