# How to display a single JavaScript Object / JSON item from API Call

Tags: javascript, json, angular, select, javascript-objects

I get data from an API Call that I already managed to display in a table. Now, when you click on some Item of the table I want to show a more detailled view of this item.

So when I open the link localhost:4200/detail/12 I want to display data from the object with the id=12. But I cannot figure out how to do this.

I currently get the id of the selected person like this from the people.component.html

```html
...
        <tr *ngFor="let data of data" routerLink="/detail/{{data.person_id}}">
            <td>{{data.person_id}}</td>
            <td>{{data.name}}</td>
        </tr>
...
```

The data of the API is in JSON format:

```
[{"person_id":"1","name":"Tom"},{"person_id":"2","name":"Clarissa"},{"person_id":"4","name":"Micky"},...]
```

but the displayed (in the Browser) data is logged as JavaScript Objects:

```
0:
   person_id: 1
   name: "Tom"
2:
   person_id: 2
   name: "Clarissa"
3:
   person_id: 4
   name: "Micky"
...
```

So how do I have to adapt the people-detail.component.ts and people-detail.component.html to display just the data of the selected Item (e.g. with the person_id=12) instead of all the items (that is what happens currently)?

This is how my people-detail.component.ts currently looks like

```
...
export class PeopleDetailComponent implements OnInit {
public data: any = []
  constructor(
    public http: HttpClient, 
    private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

getData(){
    const person_id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('person_id');
    const url ='http://localhost:4000/api/allpeople'
    this.http.get(url).subscribe
      (data => this.data = data);
  }

  ngOnInit() : void{
    this.getData()
  }
```

and this is my current people-detail.component.html:

```html
<div *ngFor="let data of data">
    <div>
        <span>id1: </span>
        {{data.regulation_id}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/42841221/6600549

Comment: the console.log looks correct, what's the issue? what determines which item is `the selected item`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setup an click listener as follow.

```
    <table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let data of data" (click)="onClickHandler(data.person_id)">
        <td>{{data.person_id}}</td>
        <td>{{data.name}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

this will pass the id of selected item into the handler method.the object havid the selected id will be stored in the "selected" variable.

```
onClickHandler(id)
{
    this.selected=this.data.find(item=>{
    if(item['id']===id)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
}
```

Comment: I pass the id of the selected item into a person_id variable like this: people.component.html: `<tr *ngFor="let data of data" routerLink="/detail/{{data.person_id}}">` people-detail.component.ts: `const person_id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('person_id');` - but I don't know how to filter the data for this person_id. So I added `this.selected=this.data.find(data=>if(data[person_id']===person_id) {return true;} return flase; });` and try to display it like this in html: `<div>
        <span>id2: </span>
        {{selected.name}}
    </div>` - But it does not display the name

Comment: what does it shows? can you please demonstrate it through code-sandbox. i think i can help

Comment: it shows the word "id:" but then there is nothing - so it basically displays a list like this: id: id: id: id: id: ...

Answer (score 0):

I would go with using a resolver.

#### Routing

First declare the route of the detailed view:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'detail/:id',
    component: PersonComponent,
    resolve: { message: PersonResolver }
  }
];
```

#### Resolver

You can use the resolver wherever you want to get a person details (reusable way to get data before loading the component

Then create the resolver on the route:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRoute, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

import { of } from "rxjs";
import { delay } from "rxjs/operators";

@Injectable()
export class PersonResolver implements Resolve<Person> {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot){
    const id = route.paramMap.get('id');
    const url = 'your url here';
    return this.http.get(url);
  }

}
```

#### Extra details

- I assume that you need to create the PersonComponent with the person details to go to after you click on a person.
- I assume that you want to show details on another component as you are going with another url.

#### Show inline version

You can also take a look at this for selecting inline [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so-select-table-item?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Yes - I forgot to mention I have a detail-component - thank you for the tip

Comment: No, I do not want to show details on another component - but you are right: It makes sense to adapt the url

Comment: Ok, I added as soltion on stackblitz to show the details inline.

Answer (score 0):

You must create interface for data:

```
export interface iUsers {
    person_id: string;
    name: string;
}
```

then you must change your code to:

```
public data: iUsers[]  = []
 this.http.get<iUsers[]>(url).subscribe((res)=>{
    this.data = res
    console.log(this.data)
    })
```